# Как зациклить FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: kotlin

```
var imageLoader: ImageLoader? = null
var CURRENT_PAGE = 1
var NUM_COLLECTIONS: Int? = null
var NUM_PAGES: Int? = null

class Main : FragmentActivity() {
//переменные...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        NUM_COLLECTIONS = Integer.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("collection", 1))

        if (NUM_COLLECTIONS?.toInt() == 1) {
            NUM_PAGES =
                Integer.valueOf(resources.getStringArray(R.array.collection_1_names).size)
        }
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager) as ViewPager2
        mViewPager!!.adapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this)
        //больше кода...


    inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(activity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            val fragment = PageFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("position", position)
            bundle.putInt("collection", NUM_COLLECTIONS!!.toInt())
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return  fragment

        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES!!.toInt()
    }

    class PageFragment : Fragment() {
        private var imageResource: Int? = null
        private var textResource: Int? = null
        override fun onCreateView(
            layoutInflater: LayoutInflater,
            viewGroup: ViewGroup?,
            bundle: Bundle?
        ): View {
            val viewGroup2 =
                layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_fragment, viewGroup, false) as ViewGroup
            val textView = viewGroup2.findViewById<View>(R.id.text) as TextView
            val imageView = viewGroup2.findViewById<View>(R.id.image) as ImageView
            val linearLayout = viewGroup2.findViewById<View>(R.id.textLayout) as LinearLayout
            val arguments: Bundle? = getArguments()
            val i: Int = arguments!!.getInt("position")
            val i2:Int = arguments!!.getInt("collection")
            if (i2 == 1) {
                imageResource = Integer.valueOf(R.array.collection_1_pictures)
                textResource = Integer.valueOf(R.array.collection_1_names)
            }
        //код класса Fragment
     }

}
```

Суть в том, что в главном меню выбирается группа (коллекция), при входе в которую считываются ресурсы ( *if (i2 == 1) {*...). Как сделать чтобы картинки листались циклично?
Весь проект есть здесь:

```
https://github.com/ZakirovAlmaz/MyFirstRepository
```

Comment: Если в проект заглянет кто-то из опытных разрабов, буду рад, если укажете на неоптимальный код и подскажете как исправить. Мой первый проект на котлине, мой первый репозиторий на гитхабе, мой первый вопрос на stackoverflow =)

Answer (score 0):

Я вам предложу использовать [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2). Он работает лучше и имеет всю плюшки RecyclerView. Вот [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/surfstudio/blog/461873/) есть статья о том как с ним работать.

Теперь о решении вашего вопроса:

Задаете размер вашего списка как `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int = Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

И в методе `createFragment()`:

```
override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val positionInList: Int = position % fragmentList.size()
        return fragmentList.get(positionInList)
    }
```

В целом никто не мешает провернуть такую же штуку и с вашим адаптером.